# Storing objects in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to store objects in IsolatedStorageSettings for windows phone 7.1

the class is -

```
public class container
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public int left { get; set; }
        public int top { get; set; }
        public int[] ar { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public bool mark { get; set; }
        public int num_e { get; set; }
        public int o { get; set; }
        public bool mine { get; set; }
// some functions
    }
```

after adding the object to isolated storage, when the **.save()** statement is executed, the following error is generated

> "An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user
>   code"

Can you please tell how make it work.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

edit :: This is how I am storing.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (save_g.Contains("n"))
        {
            save_g["n"] = cons.n;       //cons is a class and n is a static int
        }
        else
            save_g.Add("n", cons.n);

        if (save_g.Contains("n_boxes"))
        {
            save_g["n_boxes"] = cons.n_boxes;   //n_boxes is a static int
        }
        else
            save_g.Add("n_boxes", cons.n_boxes);

        save_g.Save();

        string t = "";
        container c;                   //class definition as above 

        for (int i = 0; i < cons.n; i++)
        {
            t = Convert.ToString(i);
            c=new container(edge[i]);        //edge is an object of other class

            if (save_g.Contains(t))
            {
                save_g[t] = c;
            }
            else
                save_g.Add(t, c);
            save_g.Save();                  ****Here error occurs****
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cons.n_boxes; i++)
        {
            t = Convert.ToString(i + cons.n);
            c = new container(brick[i]);    //brick is an object of other class

            if (save_g.Contains(t))
            {
                save_g[t] = c;
            }
            else
                save_g.Add(t, c);
            save_g.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code you use to add the object to the isolated storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a [DataContract] attribute on the class and [DataMember] attribute on the properties you want serialized. Normally serialization should work without these but I suspect you have some types in the class that cannot be serialized and you are not showing us these. Also make sure you have a public constructor with no arguments (or have no constructors).

P.S. in the .NET convention properties are PascalCase and names of the classes are PascalCase as well.

Comment: Thanx a lot !!  I was not having a constructor with no arguments.

Dude, you are great. I searched the net like anything and no where I could find the answer.

Once again.thanx.

Answer (score 0):

i try the of have contractor   and it's not working 
@Stilgar can u guide us how to make 
Put a [DataContract] attribute on the class and [DataMember] attribute on the properties you want serialized

i put  [DataContract]  above the class name and [DataMember] above the attributes 
the calss have 2 arttributes String